# v.what.rast.points: What to fill in as 'WHERE' conditions?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, qgis-processing

In order to extract raster values in QGIS I want to use the grass command *v.what.rast.points* in the toolbox. But the process won't start - it claims: "Where conditions of SQL statement without 'where' keyword". 
What am I supposed to fill in?

Another problem: I created an extra attribute column for the extracted values to be stored in (type: string; length: 7) , but it won't show in the selection tab of the v.what.rast.pints tool. Only the ID field can be chosen. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` parameter lets you specify which field and values you want to use in the calculation.

For example, if you have an `id` field and you only want to retrive the values for those points with an id less than 50, then you would use:

```
id < 50
```

If you want to use all values in a field (i.e. all features), you can just type in the field name:

```
id
```

---

In terms of the fields, it is mentioned in the [GRASS v.what.rast help page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.what.rast.html) that the field type **must** be numeric:

- Integer
- Float
- Double

So you will need to create a **numeric field**, not string, in order to store the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joseph. It worked very well. But only after I copied the files (shapefile and tiff) from the folder it was in originally to another one. Before I had an error because it couldn't find the files. Do you know if it is a problem for Grass and Saga tools when the folder the data is stored in or the file's names contain letters like "ü" "ö" "ß"etc.?

Comment: @Vogon_Jeltz - Most welcome! And yes, very likely. There have been a number of questions asking this here on GIS:SE where the main solution was to make sure the file names (and username) did not include those sort of characters :)